# Row click event not fired after search in bootstrap table

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Below is my jQuery DataTables initialization code:

```
oStudyDetails = $('#tblStudyAllData').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bRetrieve": true,
    "bSort": false,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sScrollY": winH - 178,
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    "aLengthMenu": [[100, 150, 200, -1], [100, 150, 200, "All"]],
    "aaSorting": [[1, "desc"]]               
});
```

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnEdit" runat="server" OnClick="EditME" ToolTip="Click To Edit" CssClass="btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-sm">
<span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-edit"></span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Please show your code for attaching the row click event handler.

Comment: I am using asp.net, and calling bootstrap dialog from code behind , below is the code.
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.[GetType](), "newStudy", "$('#newStudy').modal();", True)
But after putting search, this dialog doesn;t open.

Comment: This is not a row click event handler, please show how you attach your row click event handler. And please update your question instead of posting code in the comments.

Comment: I am sorry, i am not able to edit question, 
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnEdit" runat="server" OnClick="EditME" ToolTip="Click To Edit" CssClass="btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-sm"> <span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-edit"></span>                                                             </asp:LinkButton>

Comment: It is a little bit confusing. The `RegisterStartupScript` -> `$('#newStudy').modal();` seems not to have anything to do with the dataTable or the markup ...?

Comment: @davidkonrad, see the updated question `OnClick="EditME"`.